# MVC 5 Catch All not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't get a catch all route to work in MVC. I have tried to implement what is shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538574/mvc-5-attributerouting-catch-all), but it does not work. I have a controller called OnlineController with an Index action. My RouteConfig.cs is set up like this:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
             routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
             routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

             routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
                 UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute("RouteName", "{*url}", new { controller = 
                       "Online", action = "Index" });
         }
```

Browsing to the following URL

> Blockquote http://mysite/online/something

gives a 404. Why is it not caught and redirected to the index action on the Online controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to catch all routes you should delete `"Default"` route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

     routes.MapRoute("RouteName", "{*url}", new { controller = "Online", action = "Index" });
}
```

Routes are chosen in the order they were mapped and your url matches `"Default"` route.

If you want to catch some routes for existing controllers and actions you can use your `"Default"` route, but with constraints:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
         constraints: new { controller = "Home|Home2", action = "Index|Index2"}
        );

    routes.MapRoute("RouteName", "{*url}", new { controller = 
                   "Online", action = "Index" });
 }
```

Now, if you controller name is `"Home"` or `"Home2"` and action name is `"Index"` or `"Index2"` these routes will be handled by existing controllers and actions, if other names - by `"Online"` controller

Comment: Is there a way to do this, but still catch routes for controllers that already exist?